# Real time obstacle segmentation with lidar, how?

Tags: image-processing, object-detection, image-segmentation, lidar

I'm doing research work and can't figure out how to make one idea.

Let's say I have a drone with a lidar and a camera that look in the same direction(fly direction),the camera shoots 25 fps 1080p, the lidar asynchronously makes ~ 80k points over an area approximately occupying 1200px1024p (green circle) in the center of the image.

[image]

The task is to detect (in real time) obstacles along the way and also overlay graphics on the output image so that obstacles, say, from 100m to 200m, are highlighted with a red background, and from 200m to 400m, with a yellow background, and also obstacles along their contour have a solid fill line.

But at the same time, objects that do not interfere with the main trajectory of movement or near ground objects should not be highlighted (for example, the ground and a pipe running below the power line on the picture).
I don't need to define the obstacle type, I don't need a label.

[image]

In general, I need to find an "obstacle" via point cloud(and maybe with help of video frames), segment it, understand where its edges are and fill it in the image with a semi-transparent color.

Scientific articles talk about the use of edge-based, region growing, graph based, machine learning metnodes and other things, but no one describes the details, only black boxes. For my task, as I understand it, it is not advisable to use neural networks and machine learning here, because objects can be completely different - all types of trees, mountains, power lines, buildings, etc. But maybe I'm wrong, correct me.

The main problem is that I cannot find a clear description of the algorithm and a detailed description of the process of determining and segmenting an object.

If we talk about hardware, we planned to use a single-board computer or FPGA.

Comment: do you have a dataset for people to explore? real data please, or at least very convincing synthetic data, not just illustrations -- there's no point in segmenting anything before you have an actual trajectory you can place in a 3d space, along with the drone's camera and lidar in the same 3d space. then you can say what an obstacle is and what is not -- when you say "we", who all are you, and what qualifications do the individuals in your group have to approach this task? and what even is the task? the task isn't what you ask about. what you ask about is your approach to a part of the task

Comment: I don’t have datasets because everything I wrote in the post is still at the idea stage and I’m thinking about which software algorithm to apply in general. That's why I'm asking about what method to determine all possible types of obstacles, maybe not necessarily follow the path of neural networks and training datasets? 
We are a group of 3 people, fpga disigner, embedded programmer and electronic engineer we have no experience in such tasks, that's why I'm here.